# Overriding KinematicBody2D movement within Area2D?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to create a windy area within which the player would be pushed continuously to the left <-
[image]

So far this is what I've come up with for the `WindyArea`:

```
extends Area2D

var bodies_within=[] # saves bodies within the area which have "direction" property

func _physics_process(delta): # the "wind" process
    for body in bodies_within:
        body.direction.x-=50 # constantly pushing x back by 50
        body.direction=body.move_and_slide(body.direction) 

func _body_entered(body):
    if("direction" in body): # if body has direction then append it to the array
        bodies_within.append(body)
        set_physics_process(true) # turn on the "wind"

func _body_exited(body):
    if(body in bodies_within):
        bodies_within.erase(body)
    
    if!(len(bodies_within)): # if no bodies are left within the area then turn off the "wind"
        set_physics_process(false)

func _ready():
    set_physics_process(false)
    
    self.connect("body_entered",self,"_body_entered")
    self.connect("body_exited",self,"_body_exited")
```

and for my Player body (just for reference, I'm trying not to change this script and having to create a new windy function in it):

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var direction:Vector2
var gravity_speed=4500
var jump_speed=-1500
var descend_speed=50
var horizontal_speed=600

func _physics_process(delta):
    direction.x=Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    direction.x*=horizontal_speed
    
    if(is_on_floor()):
        if(Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up")):
            direction.y=jump_speed
    
    ## Movement ##
    direction.y += gravity_speed * delta + descend_speed * Input.get_action_strength("ui_down")
    direction=move_and_slide(direction,Vector2.UP)
```

but it only works in pushing the player back when the player is not given any user input and the body is static, but when the player is given user input it does not seem to work, instead it starts moving faster (I'm guessing since `move_and_slide` is being called twice?)

So is there any fix or alternate solution which involves the same approach of not having to change the player script (much) and instead hands the movement alteration to the Area2D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to offer an entirely different approach: gravity overrides.

Most tutorials out there have you hard code the gravity in the player character. *In fact, you are doing that.* Well, As Dr. Evil would put it: How about "No"?

---

There is a global gravity that you can get from project settings. You can get like this:

```
var g_scale:float = ProjectSettings.get("physics/2d/default_gravity")
var g:Vector2 = ProjectSettings.get("physics/2d/default_gravity_vector") * g_scale
```

Which, perhaps you don't want. However, you might find useful to express the gravity you want as a multiple of this gravity.

```
var g_scale:float = ProjectSettings.get("physics/2d/default_gravity")
var g:Vector2 = ProjectSettings.get("physics/2d/default_gravity_vector") * g_scale

gravity = g * g_factor
```

Why? Because we are going to use the `Area2D` to modify the gravity, and then you can apply the same multiplier to the gravity you get.

So, as you might be aware, the `Area2D` has "physics override" properties which allow you to modify the gravity.

Which begs the question? How do you query the gravity under which your kinematic body is? Well, like this:

```
var gravity = Physics2DServer.body_get_direct_state(get_rid()).total_gravity
```

And, yes, you could apply a factor:

```
gravity = Physics2DServer.body_get_direct_state(get_rid()).total_gravity * g_factor
```

Now you use this gravity for your motion. And you make an `Area2D` that overrides the default gravity with an horizontal component. The player character falls according to the modified gravity, which also means it moves side ways. Ta-da! "wind".

Be aware that this implies to drop the assumption that gravity is along the `y` axis. You could do it like this: `direction += gravity * delta`.

---

Ok, ok, ok, let us say you don't want to do that. What you could do is expose either a velocity or acceleration property that the `Area2D` can set to the bodies that enter.

For example:

```
var area_effect_velocity:Vector2
```

Then the `Area2D` does this:

```
func _body_entered(body):
    if("area_effect_velocity" in body):
        bodies_within.append(body)
        body.area_effect_velocity = Vector2(-50.0, 0.0)

func _body_exited(body):
    if(body in bodies_within):
        bodies_within.erase(body)
        body.area_effect_velocity = Vector2.ZERO
```

Then you can add that in your motion. For example:

```
direction += area_effect_velocity
```

---

**Addendum on overlapping `Area2D`**:

With the gravity override approach, you can set the space override to "Combine", and Godot solves that for you.

With the other approach, you can handle it by offsets:

```
var effect_velocity := Vector2(-50.0, 0.0)

func _body_entered(body):
    if("area_effect_velocity" in body):
        bodies_within.append(body)
        body.area_effect_velocity += effect_velocity

func _body_exited(body):
    if(body in bodies_within):
        bodies_within.erase(body)
        body.area_effect_velocity -= effect_velocity
```

And that would avoid extra checking.

Comment: [Always charming to read you answers!](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/017/204/CaptainAmerica1_zps8c295f96.JPG) but I'll be honest with you chief the first solution seems overkill having to change gravity and make gravity effect the horizontal moment (but still **really** helpful to know the feature exists), However the second solution seems promising but with one flaw: overlapping areas but I can already see some conditional checking to overcome it so I'll get to that, thanks as always!

Comment: Gravity and wind are just constant forces, and using the built in system to add up total constant forces in an area makes the most sense to me.