# When should I use a KinematicBody or a RigidBody for 2D platformer characters?

Tags: 2d, game-physics, godot

Which Physics body would be the best for, let's say the player character, enemy and collectibles. StaticBodies are quite different and easy but it is very confusing when we have to choose between a KinematicBody or a RigidBody.
I am recently making a 2D platformer and while I was making the enemy it struck me that I didn't which body would be the best...
I looked up at the Internet but the explanations were very vague. I ask anyone who knows, what is the difference between these two bodies and when to use one over the other?

I used a KinematicBody2D for the main player but I do not what will work best for the enemy and the collectibles, especially since my enemy will involve complex animations and attack sequence and the coin will have some basic hovering and turning animations. Also, I think that my player is not interacting with the in-game objects as was expected. I would be best if anyone could give a simple explanation for this and also a simple list of platforming elements along with the best physics object to be used...

Comment: This quesiton may be seen as subjective. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Answer (score 11):

### `RigidBody` vs `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody`

*This applies for both the 2D and 3D versions of these classes.*

The main difference between `RigidBody` and `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody` is who is in charge of moving the object.

With `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody` your code is responsible for moving the object, using `move_and_slide` et.al. methods. With `RigidBody` the physics engine is responsible for moving the object.

The `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody` classes are *intended* to be used for characters. Yet, the fact that you are responsible for moving it means that you code gravity for it. And if you want something to push the character, you have to code that on your own too.

Just to be clear: The fact that you are responsible for moving `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody` does not mean it does not interact with physics. It does. It will collide, and it will push things around (and you don't need to write code for this, however you might improve upon the default behavior, see [Kinematic to Rigid body interaction](http://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/3.x/physics/kinematic_to_rigidbody/)).

*The question "can things push the character?" can often be the deciding factor between `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody` and `RigidBody`.*

So, yes, you can use `RigidBody` for a character. And it it might be worth it if `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody` is giving you much trouble. However, avoid moving it directly, so you do not fight the physics engine (e.g. the physics engine wants to move the object one way, and your code wants to move it another way).  If you need to, you can take control of the `RigidBody` (which might require to use `_integrate_forces`, or changing its `mode`, or talking to the `PhysicsServer` class) but most of the time you would be using impulses and forces to move the `RigidBody` around. *A notable gotcha case being [teleporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75902594/402022).*

Similarly, you could, in theory approach the behavior of a `RigidBody` using a `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody` (with the help of other nodes, notably an `Area`), but is a bigger challenge.

---

### Your Questions

**Characters**

> I used a KinematicBody2D for the main player but I do not what will work best for the enemy […] especially since my enemy will involve complex animations and attack sequence

Figure out what you want, and then on top of which it will be easier to build it. *Yes. Not on top of what you can built it, there will be multiple options. And not on top of what you should built it either. But on top of what it is easier.*

As I said earlier, you can use the question: "can things push the character?" if yes, then prefer a `RidigBody`, otherwise I suggest `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody`.

*By the way even not using `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody`, nor `RigidBody`, nor `StaticBody` nor `Area` is an option. You could work at a lower level and talk with `PhysicsServer` directly. Which is not easier… [yet doable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71622366/402022). So, do you need to? Probably not, unless you really need to squish for performance (and you only really get there when you many objects - e.g. a bullet hell game - which you replace with a single node).*

---

> Also, I think that my player is not interacting with the in-game objects as was expected

I believe you need the solution covered by [Kinematic to Rigid body interaction](http://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/3.x/physics/kinematic_to_rigidbody/) (which I also linked above).

---

**Collectibles**

> and the collectibles […] the coin will have some basic hovering and turning animations

If nothing pushes it, and it pushes nothing, then use `Area`. *Even if it does move around.*

---

### On using `Area` for the player character

I want to point out that the official tutorial uses `Area` for the player character, which is also an option. In the tutorial game, the player pushes nothing, and nothing pushes it, it just needs to detect other objects for which `Area` is sufficient. However, I find that using `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody` is a better recommendation for beginners. *In particular, beginners might want to transfer what what they learned in the tutorial to games where `Area` is not a good option for the player character.*

---

### Common `Node`s for platforming games

> I would be best if anyone could give a simple explanation for this and also a simple list of platforming elements along with the best physics object to be used…

Games are different. But sure, let us talk about the most generic cases, but remember that this is not an straitjacket. These are the usual nodes starting from the use case:

- Static Platforms and Walls: `StaticBody`.
- Moving Platforms: In Godot 4 use `AnimatableBody`. in Godot 3 use `KinematicBody` (e.g. moved by `AnimationPlayer` or a `Tween`). *In some cases an `AnimatableBody` that is not moving by itself, but it is a child of a moving object, does not behave as expected... Try using an `StaticBody` or a `CharacterBody`. Worse case: write the code in the `AnimationPlayer` to follow the other object.*
- Characters: `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody`.
- Projectiles: `Area`.
- Collectibles: `Area`.
- Throwables and Pushables: `RigidBody`.

Some other things I want to mention:

- You can make platforms bouncy using the `physics_material_override` property.
- You might also do static platforms with a `TileMap` in 2D or a `GridMap` in 3D.
- Use `StaticBody` for conveyor belts.
- Use `StaticBody` for hidden objects that are detected with `Area`※.
- If you need to change gravity or apply a force in an area, you use `Area`※※.
- If you need something to trigger when the player steps on it, use `Area`.
- Similarly, if you need interactive objects (the player approaches it, and then presses a key) use an `Area` (either the character has an area where it detects the object, or the object has an area where it detects the player, I prefer the latter).
- Use `RayCast` for line of sight checks. You can have an `Area` for the vision range of an enemy, and then check line of sight with `RayCast` for each one (call `force_raycast_update` if you are moving the `RayCast` from code, which you probably would be).
- If there is an explosion, and you need to push away things that are nearby, use an `Area` to detect them. *Combine with the `RayCast` again, so objects can be under cover.*
- If you need to detect the end of a platform, to prevent a character from falling off, use a `RayCast` offset so it is ahead of the character, and have it pointing downwards.

※: For example you can dedicate a physics layer for "audible" objects, then spawn a `StaticBody` in that layer where something makes a sound, and give the enemies that can "hear" an `Area` that detects body in that layer.

※※: Since you write the gravity code for `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody` that means either reading the gravity from `PhysicsServer.body_get_direct_state(get_rid()).total_gravity` or otherwise communicating the change to the `KinematicBody`/`CharacterBody`. For example see [Overriding KinematicBody2D movement within Area2D?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75242908/402022).

---

I have an explanation of (almost) everything you need to know about setting physics in Godot [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022).