# Godot 4 How to shoot?

Tags: game-development, godot4

I'm new at Godot and I want to develop a small 2d tank game. But I'm stuck at shooting. I've watched many tutorials, but they are for me beginner far too complicated. So I want to ask if it's possible to move an object into a direction with just an angle to prevent using coordinates.

Until now I have programmed that if space is pressed the bullet appears and if it touches something, it dissappear and create an event

Answer (score -1):

I argue [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75619718/402022) that you should use `Area`(`2D`/`3D`) for projectiles.

The `Area`(`2D`/`3D`) has a `global_position` that you can use to move it.

Since you want to work with an angle, you can define a vector in the appropriate direction like this:

```
var direction := Vector2.RIGHT.rotated(angle)
```

You will also need a speed:

```
var direction := Vector2.RIGHT.rotated(angle)
var velocity := direction * speed
```

And then you can move your `Area2D` by that:

```
func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    global_position += velocity * delta
```

I hereby remind you that velocity is displacement over time, and delta is the elapsed time between frames. So when you multiply velocity by delta you get displacement... Which is the change in position.

---

If for whatever reason your projectile is a kinematic body, you would just set its `velocity`, and then call `move_and_slide` in `_physics_process`.

---

*You are going to use vectors and you are going to like it.*