# Collision walls in Godot

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm creating a game using Godot Engine and I can't figure out how to create a wall to prevent a player from walking out of the screen.

The player is able to walk out of the screen window. How do I prevent it from happening?

I tried to use the CollisionShape2D node but I don't think I know how to use it properly in a way that it works like I want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: What I explain here also holds for the 3D counterpart of these nodes.*

---

`CollisionShape2D` and `CollisionPolygon2D` do nothing on their own. Their purpose is to provide a shape for a parent `CollisionObject2D`.

---

There are two kinds of `CollisionObject2D`s: `Area2D` and `PhysicsBody2D`.

The `Area2D` will detect other bodies or areas, but won't stop them from moving, which is not what you want.

There are three kinds of `PhysicsBody2D`:

- `CharacterBody2D`: which is intended to be moved via script, usually to make character controllers.
- `RigidBody2D`: which is moved by the physics engine, usually to make bodies that can be pushed around by other bodies.
- `StaticBody2D`: which either do not move (or have a predefined motion). This is the one you want.

Thus, you would setup a `StaticBody2D` with a child `CollisionShape2D` or `CollisionPolygon2D`.

---

Now, I'm also going to point out that physic bodies interact with physic bodies. If you, for example, have created your character as an `Sprite2D`, since the `Sprite2D` only cares about graphics and does not have collisions it will not be stopped by the `StaticBody2D`.

So you usually make your character as a body that can collide (usually a `CharacterBody2D`, sometimes a `RigidBody2D`), and it would, of course, have a child `CollisionShape2D` or `CollisionPolygon2D`, and also as child it can have your `Sprite2D` or whatever else you need.

By making the `Sprite2D` and other `Node2D`s children of the physics body, they will move with it.

---

If you haven't decided between `CharacterBody2D` and `RigidBody2D`, I go into more length on which kind of node to use for what [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75619718/402022). *A very good abstract is the following: If something else can push it, use a `RigidBody2D`. following the link you get the nuance and what to use for specific cases.*

---

For the `CollisionShape2D` to set its `shape` property to a `Shape2D`.

About making the boundary for the game, the recommendation is to use `WorldBoundaryShape2D` for each edge. However, thick enough `RectangleShape2D` would also work.

Alternatively, although not recommended, you could use a `CollisionPolygon2D` covering the play area, and set its `build_mode` to `BUILD_SEGMENTS`, which results in a hollow polygon, so other bodies can be inside of it.

Comment: thank you so much, i'm actually gonna tear up <3