# How to move 2D Node to given coordinates in Godot 4?

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm extremely new to Godot 4 and trying to create a basic game where the player has to dodge falling rocks.
I'm currently trying to make the rock move back up to top after it hits the bottom (I have an Area2D which sends a signal when the rock enters it), but to no avail. I have tried code such as "self.position = Vector2(xpos, ypos)" among others but the rock just stays at the bottom. The rock successfully moves to a random location when first entering the scene, but not when the function is called when the rock enters the Area2D.

Here is my code if you want to look:

### [Rock Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b44cL.png)

Here is a screenshot of my level scene and rock scene:

[Level Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz2uu.png)
[Rock Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDRWX.png)

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Area2D` `body_entered` signal detects when a *body* enters. Where *body* refer to a `PhysicsBody2D` (which is either an `StaticBody2D`, `CharacterBody2D` or `RigidBody2D`)... Or a `TileMap`.

However, you have used a generic `Node` as root for the `Rock` scene, as a result the `Area2D` won't be able to detect it.

---

Furthermore a `CollisionShape2D` on its own does nothing. It should be a child of a `CollisionObject2D` (which is either an `StaticBody2D`, `CharacterBody2D` or `RigidBody2D`... Or an `Area2D`).

---

I did notice you happen to have a `TileMap`.

I do not know if the `TileMap` has collision defined (you would do that by editing its tile in the `TileSet`).

If the `TileMap` has collision defined, it might be triggering the signal. However, the object you would get as argument `body` of the `body_entered` would be the `TileMap` not the `Rock` (thus the check `body == self` in `Rock` would fail).

---

*I do not see code for the `Rock` moving (aside from the teleportation), so you can still decide which kind of body it will be. Another of my answers might help you decide: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75619718/402022).*

*I have gone into more detail on how to setup physics in Godot [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022).*