# RayCast3d not colliding with object in godot 4.2.1

Tags: game-development, godot4

I am trying to create an FPS game in godot 4, and I run into an issue where the RayCast does not collide with a temporary object that would give the player ammo. When I try to interact, nothing occurs, and when I have checked, the RayCast is not colliding.

I tried changing the collision mask and the collision layer, neither have worked.

Here's the code for the player:

```
extends CharacterBody3D

var health = 100.0
var VC_REP = 0.0
var RB_REP = 0.0

var ammo = 30
var ammo_cap = 150
var mags = 5

var quest_title = "Operation: Viewpoint"
var quest_desc = "Infiltrate Outlook Alpha"

var speed
const SPRINT_SPEED = 8.0
const WALK_SPEED = 5.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = 4.5
const SENSITIVITY = 0.003

const BOB_FREQ = 2.0
const BOB_AMP = 0.08
var t_bob = 0.0

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = 9.8

var bullet = load("res://bullet.tscn")
var instance

@onready var head = $Head
@onready var camera = $Head/Camera3D

@onready var gun_anim = $"../Player/Head/Camera3D/ar1/AnimationPlayer"
@onready var gunbarrel = $"../Player/Head/Camera3D/ar1/M4a1/RayCast3D"

@onready var interaction_ray = $Head/Camera3D/RayCast3D

func _ready():
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)
    

func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        head.rotate_y(-event.relative.x * SENSITIVITY)
        camera.rotate_x(-event.relative.y * SENSITIVITY)
        camera.rotation.x = clamp(camera.rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-40), deg_to_rad(60))

func _physics_process(delta):
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y -= gravity * delta

    # Handle jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint"):
        speed = SPRINT_SPEED
    else:
        speed = WALK_SPEED

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var input_dir = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "up", "down")
    var direction = (head.transform.basis * Vector3(input_dir.x, 0, input_dir.y)).normalized()
    if is_on_floor():
        if direction:
            velocity.x = direction.x * speed
            velocity.z = direction.z * speed
        else:
            velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, direction.x * speed, delta * 7.0)
            velocity.z = lerp(velocity.z, direction.z * speed, delta * 7.0)
    else:
        velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, direction.x * speed, delta * 3.0)
        velocity.z = lerp(velocity.z, direction.z * speed, delta * 3.0)
    
    if is_on_floor() and health == 0:
        velocity.x = 0
        velocity.z = 0
    
    t_bob += delta * velocity.length() * float(is_on_floor())
    camera.transform.origin = _headbob(t_bob)
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("shoot"):
        if (!gun_anim.is_playing() and ammo != 0):
            gun_anim.play("Shoot")
            instance = bullet.instantiate()
            instance.position = gunbarrel.global_position
            instance.transform.basis = gunbarrel.global_transform.basis
            get_parent().add_child(instance)
            ammo -= 1
        
    if (Input.is_action_just_pressed("reload") and ammo == 0 and mags != 0):
        ammo += 30
        mags -= 1
    
    if interaction_ray.get_collider() != null and interaction_ray.get_collider().is_in_group("Ammo"):
        print("Ammo")
    
    print(ammo)
    print(mags)
    
    move_and_slide()

func _headbob(time) -> Vector3:
    var pos = Vector3.ZERO
    pos.y = sin(time * BOB_FREQ) * BOB_AMP
    return pos
```

And here is the code for the temporary object.

```
extends MeshInstance3D

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.

# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    pass

func give_ammo(mags):
    mags += 3
    queue_free()
    return mags
```

The RayCast is supposed to call the `give_ammo()` function, and use `mags` to call the variable.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RayCast3D` does physics queries. `MeshInstance3D` is concerned with graphics.

These `Node`s do not interact.

Create instead one of these:

- `Area3D` (and set `RayCast3D` to collide areas and not bodies), and add `CollisionShape3D` or `CollisionPolygon3D` children. *This would be my recommendation for collectible items.*
- `PhysicsBody3D` (e.g. `StaticBody3D`), and add `CollisionShape3D` or `CollisionPolygon3D` children. *This is the most common case.*
- `CSG*` and set their `use_collision` to `true`. *Might not have the best performance, but sometimes works better.*
- `GridMap` might also work. *It is overkill for this usecase.*

So the `RayCast3D` can detect them.

*I have an explanation of what kind of `Node` to use for different use cases [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75619718/402022).*

You might still add the `MeshInstance3D` as a child of them. In particular, since `Area3D` and `PhysicsBody3D` are only concerned with physics, they don't have a graphical representation by default.

---

You also want to make sure that the collision mask of the raycast overlaps the collision layer of whatever you want it to detect.

If you are still having problems with the detection, you can enable "Visible Collision Shapes" in the "Debug" menu, so Godot renders the colliders during testing, so you can see what is going on.

---

If you need more help setting up your physics objects, I'll refer you to: [How do I detect collisions in Godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022).