# How to make wall collision with staticbody2d & collisionshape2d ( using an area2D for player with collisionshape2d as a child ) in GODOT?

Tags: 2d, game-development, collision, godot, godot4

I wanted to know if I can make a player with **area2d** with a child **collisionshape2d**
and then make a collision with my walls having a node of **staticbody2d**

which has two childs in it of **collisionbody2d**

but as **area2d** doesnt know how to collide ig, what would your suggestion to make the collision happen between them..

I don't **area_entered** is any useful here.. **area_touched** might be useful but doesnt exist.. but there is **oneway collision** option in the **collisionshape2d** property..
is that option for that use?

Thanks!
please help me understand better..

I tried to use layers but they didn't work for me

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want. You say an `Area2D` and a `StaticBody2D`, presumably the `Area2D` is what moves, right? `area_entered` detects when an area enters another area, so this would be `body_entered`... Which makes me think you are missing some basics, please have a look at [How do I detect collisions in Godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69731270/402022). - Anyway, if the `Area2D` is what is moving there is a chance that you are better off not using an `Area2D` at all, perhaps a `ShapeCast2D` or `intersect_shape`, but I lack information to make a suggestion.

Comment: Yes you got it right.. and I see I should avoid it because area2d is moving, which makes me ask that what exactly do we need staticbody2d for then? and thanks for answering you're helpful to me!

Comment: I do not know what you want to do. I go over common use cases in [When should I use a KinematicBody or a RigidBody for 2D platformer characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75619718/402022).

Comment: I am just making a spaceship as area2d and the space boundary, my walls as staticbody2d and trying to have collision between them and I'm understanding now why I shouldn't do it..

Comment: Also I know the characterbody2d has everything which can solve my issue but I thought if it's possible lets make a collision from  scratch and see how it works.. I'm a beginner you see.. so trying hard on me first to learn better.. but thank you for your help I will follow what's recommended..